# Ошибка в парсинге XML

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть xml, приходящий с CURL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<merchant.response>
 <operation wmtransid="782312540" wminvoiceid="336870756">
  <amount>1</amount>
  <operdate>20121126 03:57:10</operdate>
  <purpose>test</purpose>
  <pursefrom>R256020338309</pursefrom>
 </operation>
 <retval>0</retval>
 <retdesc></retdesc>
</merchant.response>

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Все попытки спарсить - безуспешны.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
print_r($xml);
```

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/user1734/public_html/system/modules/settings/balance/info_xml.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /home/user1734/public_html/system/modules/settings/balance/info_xml.php(22): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('1') #1 {main} thrown in /home/user1734/public_html/system/modules/settings/balance/info_xml.php on line 22`

В чем проблема?

Comment: Как до curl_exec($ch) инициализируется $ch и какие опции у curl?
Дело в том, что у вас возвращается не XML код а "1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас при вызове curl_exec($ch) возвращается статус а не строка с XML.

Нужно сделать **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);** для того чтобы возвращался результат в переменную $result.

[Вот здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) можно посмотреть список всех опций.

Comment: @KryDos, всегда знал, что на ХэшКоде умные люди :) Спасибо!